# Linear Layout clicável

Tags: android, android-layout

Como que eu faço para que meu layout seja clicável?

Por exemplo, divido a tela em 2 layouts, 1 verde com 50% da tela e o outro vermelho com os outros 50%.
Como torna-los clicáveis?

Answer (score 5):

Defina no XML dos seus layouts a tag:

```
android:clickable=“true”
```

Depois disso é só tratar o click como você trata o click em qualquer outra view, como em um botão, por exemplo.

Comment: Obrigado!! ajudou mt

Answer (score 2):

```
LinearLayout meuComponente = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.meu_componente);
meuComponente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Insira qualquer comportamento aqui. (:
    }
});
```

Não se esqueça de setar o atributo do seu `LinearLayout`:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Caso deseje que os elementos dentro do `LinearLayout` não sejam clicáveis, utilize: `android:clickable="false"` para todos os elementos.